# react native version check package make app crash

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have installed react-native-version-check by yarn into my project when I use some functions the app crash sending me this message:
WARN  [TypeError: Network request failed]

this only happens when I'm using these functions only:
VersionCheck.getLatestVersion()
VersionCheck.needUpdate()

The same thing happens using react-native-check-version package function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search in the library to know what was making this error
it was actually the fetch API
I had to put these lines of code in my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   api(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.7.2"))
   api("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
   api("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")
}
```

after adding those lines everything worked just fine

Answer (score 2):

There has been some unresolved issues regarding this package and especially those functions that you mentioned. I had faced the same issue previously, my suggestion would be to go with a backend driven version check. You can maintain a table to store the latest version, force update flag, etc. Also since these 2 functions are promise, you can check what they are returning.

```
VersionCheck.getLatestVersion({
  forceUpdate: true,
  provider: () => fetch('http://your.own/api')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(({version}) => version),   // You can get latest version from your own api.
}).then(latestVersion =>{
  console.log(latestVersion);
});

VersionCheck.needUpdate()
  .then(async res => {
    console.log(res.isNeeded);    // true
    if (res.isNeeded) {
      Linking.openURL(res.storeUrl);  // open store if update is needed.
    }
  });
```

Comment: Ohh I didn't know that since there is no one's talking about it on GitHub or StackOverflow but thanks a lot for your answer 
and do you know any other similar package with the same functionality ?

Comment: What is the promise returning you when you use this? there is also some react-native-check-version package available.

Answer (score 0):

version "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.3", is up to date
documentation link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-version-check?activeTab=versions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).